# Print in ERB without <%=?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Sometimes it's more convenient to print in <%%>. How to do it in Rails?

Comment: @JohnTopley A loop which only calls many other partials.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat

Should be what you are looking for.

E.g. the following statement using `concat`:

```
<% concat "Output" %>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<%= "Output" %>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work with `puts` like `echo` works in PHP?

Comment: STDOUT goes somewhere else with Rails, you probably *could* do something nasty so that all STDOUT goes to your erb template, but, don't.

Comment: @Chloe, be grateful for that. :)

Comment: @Chloe - STDOUT goes to the log. I've found this default behaviour very handy when running Passenger (for example) where a quick print can help debug.

Comment: To print HTML, use for e.g. `<% concat "<br>".html_safe %>`

Answer (score 7):

In ERB:
The <% %> signify that there is Ruby code here to be interpreted.
The <%= %> says output the ruby code, ie display/print the result.

So it seems you need to use the extra = sign if you want to output in a standard ERB file.

Otherwise, you could look at alternatives to ERB which require less syntax,.. maybe try something like HAML. http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html

```
Example:

# ERB
<strong><%= item.title %></strong>

# HAML
%strong= item.title
```

Is that more convenient?

Answer (score 4):

[erb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html#M000301) has two method to evaluate inline ruby expressions.  The `<%` which evaluates the expression and the `<%=` which evaluates and prints.  There is no global object to print to within the binding context.

As mentioned by Omar, there is a **[concat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001742)** method, which is part of ActionView.  This will do what you want.

Unlike a scripting language escape, there is no default output for erb.  Since erb is simply a function, and given a template and binding will return a variable, it returns the values of text and functions recursively.

There is hot debate as to how much logic should be allowed in a view, but *as little as possible* is what most people aim for.  If you are putting more code than text in the view, you may want to consider refactoring your code.